# React Redux - is it ok to throw every state into connecting my components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As stated in the question, say, I have a store with multiple reducers (>10 Redux states).

Typically in a component, whenever we want to access a particular state from the store, we would do something like:

```
//only 3 needed states
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    prop1: state.ReducerOne.prop1,
    prop2: state.ReducerOne.prop2,
    prop3: state.ReducerTwo.prop1,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

However, we would only throw in states that we need in order for the component to function.

Is it alright to throw in EVERY single state in the store into `mapStateToProps` to every component even when we do not need to use them? Will the performance be affected in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it alright to throw in EVERY single state in the store into
>   mapStateToProps to every component even when we do not need to use
>   them?

It will cause *unnecessary* re-renders. So, if you don't need to use them, then do not put them in `mapStateToProps`.

> Will the performance be affected in any way?

Yes, you don't want unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: I disagree with this.  The redux provider for react will verify any changes in state and even if you have 1000 different states, if the original is returned back it will not re-render.  If this were the case you would need a new redux state **and** a new react-redux provider component for **every single state**.  Doable, but unnecessary.